# Setting manual control properties doesn't work before an animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I have an image in a `Canvas`, but when I use `DoubleAnimation` to move it and then use `Canvas.SetLeft(image)`, the method is ignored, the only way to move it again is with animations. What's wrong with `Canvas.SetLeft(control)`?

Here is an explanation with images of what's happening:

[image]

The default coin position is 0 in `Canvas.Left` property.

[image]

I move it with the mouse with the next code;

```
Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(cCoinContainer);
Canvas.SetLeft(iCoin, p.X);
```

[image]

And when the mouse left the Canvas, the animation moves the coin to it's original `Canvas.Left` position.

The problem is when I do it again (move the coin with the mouse with `Canvas.SetLeft(iCoin, p.X);` it's completely ignored, only works with animations.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be one of general issues addressed in MSDN post about [Animation Tips and Tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613592%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). To solve the problem, try to set animation's `FillBehavior` to `Stop` :

```
<Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation 
        FillBehavior="Stop"
        ......
        />
</Storyboard>
```

> By setting FillBehavior to Stop, you tell the animation to stop affecting its target property after it reaches the end of its active period. [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to make the image draggable with the mouse? if am right; 
you should add a MouseCapture() on the rectangle to update the mouse position with mouse animation
and call RealeaseMouseCapture when you finish; at MouseUp Event
cause the GetMousePosition return the current mouse position fore once.
good luck.
if you need some, feel free to ask!